# SKSpriteNode moveTo:X for all in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

```
        for (int i = 0; i < [playerCards count]; i++) {
            int cardsLaid = i * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
            CGPoint forPoint = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4)) + cardsLaid, 0.0);

            playerCards[i]

            [??? runAction:[SKAction moveTo:forPoint duration:0.6]];
        }
```

I need some sort of `SKSpriteNode withName : X move to point : forPoint;`

Not much more to describe, basically that cards move from one position leaving a gap. Then after that card is moved from the Players array, them cards should tighten up as they were before. However, targetting the CardSpriteNodes is proving difficult.

As you can see with the position it will filter through all the cards in the array and i will multiply the gap between them therefore resorting them. But I cannot target the specific cards in the array, they are stored in the array by their .names

**-EDIT-**

[image]

As you can see, after they've moved up, it leaves a gap from where they were taken. Above cards are now `cardsPlayed` and below cars are `playerCards` NSMutableArrays

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[CardSpriteNode class]]) {
        int add = (int)[playerCards count] * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
        CGPoint origPos = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2.8 + add, -218);

        if ([cardsPlayed containsObject:node.name]) {
            //Card is already played, return to original position and remove from array.
            CGPoint point = origPos;

            [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:0.6]];

            node.zPosition = zPosCount;
            zPosCount += 1;

            [cardsPlayed removeObject:node.name];
            [playerCards addObject:node.name];

            NSLog(@"this ran");
        } else {
            //Card is not already played, position to add card and add to array.
            amountOfCardsLaid = (int)[cardsPlayed count] * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
            CGPoint point = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4
            )) + amountOfCardsLaid, 0.0);
            [node runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:0.6]];

            node.zPosition = zPosCount;
            zPosCount += 1;

            [playerCards removeObject:node.name];
            [cardsPlayed addObject:node.name];

            for (int i = 0; i < [playerCards count]; i++) {
                int cardsLaid = i * (cardDisplay.size.width / 3);
                CGPoint forPoint = CGPointMake((0.5 - (self.frame.size.width / 4)) + cardsLaid, 0.0);

                playerCards[i]

                [??? runAction:[SKAction moveTo:forPoint duration:0.6]];
            }
        }

        //Hide.Unhide buttons
        if ([cardsPlayed count] == 0) {
            if (addButton.hidden == FALSE) addButton.hidden = true;
            if (cancelButton.hidden == FALSE) cancelButton.hidden = true;
        } else {
            if (addButton.hidden == TRUE) addButton.hidden = false;
            if (cancelButton.hidden == TRUE) cancelButton.hidden = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, when a card is taken from the bottom it goes to the top. When it's at the top, if it's pressed again, it will move to the last position of the bottom cards and be re-added to that array. However, I need to close the `gap` once the card has been moved upwards.

To achieve this I was going to filter through each `playerCards` array with contains the CardSpriteNode (SKSpriteNode) .name and move each one with the forloop. But cannot exactly figure out how to select each card in the `playerCard` by it's name?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you particularly need from the above

If you need to fetch card nodes you can do that using 

    enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:

Or various other methods that are available in SKNode for retrieving nodes. The problem you seem to have seems to be a coding structure issue. You must provide more details for anyone to understand what you are trying to do. From this: SKSpriteNode withName : X move to point : forPoint; it sounds like you just need to enumerate the nodes and check if the name of the node matches via the name property.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Basically as of right now, the cards move up to be played, they are removed from the `playerCards` array and placed into the `playedCards` array. Then, I want the gap that the card made to close up. and they are spaced like I described with the cards laid int, and forpoint. I'll update my question.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Updated the question for you, hopefully it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: You should put your player cards and played cards in a playedcardsnode and playercardsnode. This will let you separate the data so you can re sort cards on screen. In reality, you should have game logic in another class that has a grid, the grid will keep trac of where everything is and what spaces are occupied and so on. Since your logic isn't properly separated, this will be harder. Your best bet is to use ray casts to detect what cards are around the removed/added card.

Comment: Also, without running the code and while glancing at the code above it's still fairly hard to tell what the goal is. Readability is key in obj c code. Separate this stuff into methods and indicate what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a card game in my spare time as well so I know the issue you are looking at. I created a subclass of SKSpriteNode and in it I had keys with the different values the cards had.

However you don't even need to do that if you want to keep it more basic just set the name property of the SKSpriteNode and then use the `enumerateChildNodesWithName:` method or a `for loop` with an `if statement` like suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand you're question better. To solve the above issue, use the original point of the card and invoke a raycast using the width of that area via the right/left side and bump the distance of all nodes that have the name (lets just say you called your cards "cards") over by the appropriate distance. No particular order is required as you're moving all the node with that name by the same distance. Use

```
hitTestWithSegmentFromPoint:toPoint:options:
```

Otherwise, you must enumerate your nodes and some how label the `SKSpriteNode` object with a flag that informs you if it's Played or In Hand. When enumerating, you must get a total distance and calculate the positions each card must occupy. You should be able to use your array to note the position from left to right of the cards and multiply the index of that object by the calculated distance dividing the total distance by the total card count. (Don't forget you can get the index of an object out of an array using`indexOfObject:`on `NSArray` or `find(arr, "d")` in Swift.